# "Uninitialized Local Variable" Error, Despite Defining Variable?

Tags: c

Here's the code. It says a variable is not initialized, despite defining it at the top of the code after main function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, sum=0; i=0;
    printf("Please enter a number to evaluate\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        double(sum) = sum + double(1/n);
    }

    sum = (int)sum;

    if(sum == 1)
    {
        printf("Adding %d 1/%d's gives a result of 1\n",n,n);
    }
    if(sum <= 1)
    {
        printf("Adding %d 1/%d's gives a result less than 1\n",n,n);
    }
    if(sum >= 1)
    {
        printf("Adding %d 1/%d's gives a result greater than 1\n",n,n);
    }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: After getting answers do not edit the question. It will mislead users.

Comment: ... and potential other viewers in the future

Comment: @EdHeal; Oh yes, Of course.

Answer (score 10):

Either remove semicolon after `sum=0;` and change

```
int n, sum=0; i=0;
```

to

```
int n, sum=0, i=0;
```

or change `int n, sum=0; i=0;` to

```
int n, sum=0; int i=0;
```

---

**Side Note:**

The statement

```
double(sum) = sum + double(1/n);
```

is wrong. If you mean `double(sum)` by casting then it is not a valid syntax. If it would be like `(double)sum` then still it is wrong as `=` require l-value as its left operand.
I would suggest you to declare `sum` as `double` and rewrite it as

```
int n = 1, i;
printf("Please enter a number to evaluate\n");
scanf_s("%d",&n);
double sum = 0.0;
for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    sum = sum + (1.0/n);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually had

int n, sum=0, i=0;

and it's still giving me problems. 

"Run-Time Check Failure #3- The variable 'sum' is being used without being initialized"

Answer (score 3):

What happens if scanf_s fails? You need to initialize `n`.